# Correct URL for connecting to java jdbc

Tags: postgresql, url, jdbc

I'm having trouble setting up a connection with my database here and was wondering what I may be doing wrong.
The error is as follows:

**Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://168.16.1.128:5432/dbname
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at sample.DbConnect.getConnection(DbConnect.java:21)
    at sample.UserTest.main(UserTest.java:41)**
My connecting class looks as follows:

```
public class DbConnect {
public java.sql.Connection getConnection() throws SQLException,IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {

        java.sql.Connection conn = null;           
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://168.16.1.128:5432/dbname";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("Connected to database");
        return conn;
    }   
}
```

and heres where it gets called:

```
public class UserTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException{
        DbConnect db = new DbConnect();
        db.getConnection();
        }
}
```

I have a feeling the error may come from the way the url is written and if this is the case can someone please explain to me how to properly write the url?
This database doesnt require a password and username to be connected to. I hope anyone can be so kind as to help me.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: Sorry about that,added it above

Comment: Have you added the postgresql JDBC driver to your runtime classpath? The exception says you didn't.

Comment: Ive added these:import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

Comment: And when you have driver on classpath already you have to load pg database driver by executing `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")` before making connection.

Comment: @Almanz that's not how you add a JDBC driver to the classpath. You need to download the postgresql JDBC driver jar file, and to add it to the classpath when running your application: `java -classpath postgresql.jar:myapp.jar com.foo.bar.UserTest`.

Comment: Thanks so much! it worked

Comment: You need to include the jdbc jar in your application while trying to execute. Then only you will be able to access DriverClass. You can get them from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Comment: Title problem. You aren't 'connecting to Java JDBC'. You are connecting *to* the databae server *via* JDBC.